# Python peewee.ImproperlyConfigured: MySQL driver not installed

Tags: python, mysql-python, peewee

I tried to make a MySQL connection with peewee and followed the tutorial from their website:
[peewee quickstart](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/quickstart.html#quickstart)

So my code is the following:

```
from peewee import *

db = MySQLDatabase(
    host='127.0.0.1',
    user='root',
    password='',
    database='db_test'
)

class Person(Model):
    name = CharField()
    birthday = DateField()

    class Meta:
        database = db

class Pet(Model):
    owner = ForeignKeyField(Person, backref='pets')
    name = CharField()
    animal_type = CharField()

    class Meta:
        database = db

db.connect()

db.create_tables([Person, Pet])

db.close()
```

(My Database is from xampp)

But when i execute this code I get this error message:

> peewee.ImproperlyConfigured: MySQL driver not installed!

I tried to fix this by installing
[this](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/)
MySQL Driver. But this changed absolutely nothing. Due to me beeing new to python I have no idea what I can do to fix this, if i'm just missing a import or if I have to install a library with pip?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The docs are clear, as is the error message: http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/database.html#using-mysql

Install pymysql or mysqldb.

To use the non-standard mysql-connector driver, you need to import the `playhouse.mysql_ext` module and use the `MySQLConnectorDatabase` implementation:

http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/playhouse.html#mysql-ext

Comment: Non-standard in what sense? That it's not supported by Peewee without Playhouse?

Answer (score 13):

Install a MySQL driver:

```
pip install pymysql
```

Answer (score 1):

The docs are not that clear anymore it seems. The problem is indeed a missing MySQL driver. There are various MySQL drivers available for Python, each with their own pros and cons.

[This Github comment](https://github.com/coleifer/peewee/issues/1569#issuecomment-484128525) gives a good summary:

> - pymysql is a pure-python mysql client, works with python 2 and 3. Peewee will use attempt to use pymysql first.
> - mysqlclient uses a c extension and supports python 3. It exposes a MySQLdb module. Peewee will attempt to use this module if pymysql is not installed.
> - mysql-python is also called MySQLdb1 and is legacy and should not be used. Since this shares the same module name as mysqlclient, same applies.
> - mysql-connector python pure-python (I think??) supports python 3. To use this driver you can use playhouse.mysql_ext.MySQLConnectorDatabase.

Some additional notes:

- pymsql, being a pure-python implementation, is easy to install without many dependencies, but is really slow.
- mysqlclient is fast, but has to be compiled and thus has [additional dependencies](https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient#install). At the time of writing, on Ubuntu, those take up an additional 26 Mb of diskspace, which may be relevant if you're using containers.
- I haven't tried mysql-connector.

Comment: Connector/Python has both a pure Python and a C-based implementation that inerfaces with the MySQL C client library: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-cext.html

Comment: For those researching Connector/Python, it's mentioned a few places online that it has issues (including on the official SQLAlchemy site), but it appears none have bothered to specify what the issues are. I haven't had any problems using it for years now, and it's well documented by Oracle.